# Validating user details

Tags: php

I have a PHP function which checks if certain user details are populated and alerts the user.

I'm trying to find a better way of doing this as the user object will periodically be added to and I don't want to copy and paste if's each time. I know there is a better way of doing this but I haven't been able to get other approaches to work correctly.

The only caveat is that the user object contains some values that the users don't need to be alerted to such as an IP address so I want to be able to only pick certain values to be checked.

```
public function checkUserDetails() { //Check all user details are valid, if not warn the user
    $fullname = $this -> user -> fullname;
    $email = $this -> user -> email;
    $teamid = $this -> user -> teamid;
    $output = "";

    if (empty($fullname)) {
        $output .= "<br><a href=\"/quality/user-account.php\" class=alert-link><i class=\"fa fa-caret-right\"></i>Full Name</a>";
        $error = 1;
    }
    if (empty($email)) {
        $output .= "<br><a href=\"/quality/user-account.php\" class=alert-link><i class=\"fa fa-caret-right\"></i>Email Address</a>";
        $error = 1;
    }
    if (empty($teamid)) {
        $output .= "<br><a href=\"/quality/user-account.php\" class=alert-link><i class=\"fa fa-caret-right\"></i>Team</a>";
        $error = 1;
    }

    if ($error == 1) {
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-warning\">";
        echo "<h4><i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i><strong>WARNING</strong></h4>";
        echo "The following user details are incorrect and need updating:";
        echo $output;
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

[image]